# If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of step functions such that $(f_n) \rightarrow f$ uniformly, then $f$ is jump continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

> If exists $f_n: [a,b] \rightarrow R$ a sequence of step functions converging uniformly to $f$, prove that $f$ is jump continuous.

The first idea I had was to reduce to the case $a<x<b$ and prove that the right-limit of $f$ exists (probably the other cases will be treated similarly). I was wondering to use the following inequality:

$$|f(x)-L^+|\leq |f_n(x)-L_n^+|+|-f_n(x)+f(x)|+|-L^++L_n^+|$$

where $(L_n^+)_n$ denotes the sequence of the right limits of every $f_n$ and $L^+$ its limit (which i suppose that shall exists).

Bu i'm not sure if that sequence really converges. How to proceed with this idea? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Some definitions:

1) Given $\pi = \{t_0,\cdots,t_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$, a function  $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ such that $f$ is constant = $c_i$ for every $(t_{i-1},t_i)$ is a *step function*.

2) A function $f:(a,b) \rightarrow R$ is jump continuous if exists the right limit of $x \rightarrow a^+$, the left limit of $x\rightarrow b^-$ and both limits of $x \rightarrow c^{+,-}$ for evert $a<c<b$.

Comment: What's your definition of a "step function"?

Comment: And what does "jump continuous" mean?